# Rails postgres migration trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

rails 6.0.0 postgresql 11.5

rails db:migrate runs successfully, but there is no required column in users table. 
rails db:rollback also runs successfully even without that column.

I have only one database and config files have no mistakes.

Tried to reinstall rails, postgresql and use new database dump.

```
class AddCountryToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :country, :string
  end
end
```

migration result:

```
== 20191105100235 AddCountryToUsers: migrating ============================
-- add_column(:users, :country, :string)
   -> 0.0037s
== 20191105100235 AddCountryToUsers: migrated (0.0038s) ===================
```

rollback result:

```
== 20191105100235 AddCountryToUsers: reverting ============================
-- remove_column(:users, :country, :string)
   -> 0.0027s
== 20191105100235 AddCountryToUsers: reverted (0.0028s) ===================
```

The most interesting thing is that manual execution of sql command creates column successfully...

Comment: What does the migration and rollback return (whole stacktrace) when executed?

Comment: Added to description

Comment: I guess you were checking wrong test/dev DB :D

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Đào Minh Hạt, I have only one database, so its unlikely that i test wrong db ;)
sureshprasanna70, even after successful migration i don't have column country im users table. So would be happy to have it =)